# ClickOnce UNC command line

Tags: c#, command-line, parameters, clickonce, unc

I see a lot sample but i don't find the something good for my problem.

This problem is : I have a program made in  c#. I use the clickonce UNC system.

With the shortcut on the desktop, there is no problem.

But I want for sepecific users, add parameters like :

\server...directories...\myapplication.application /a:XXX /b:xxxx

The on the program the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` doesn't work i haven't arguments.

The other sample speak about URI, but i user UNC installation not a URI link !!

Someone have the same problem and found a solution ?

thanks

LittleJC

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with a ClickOnce application invoked via UNC path.  The only way to pass anything like command line parameters to a ClickOnce application is via URL string query parameters, but that only works when invoking via URL, not UNC.  (See Noyes: *Smart Client Deployment with ClickOnce*, chapter 8, first section.)